# Can't Install anything from Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, 15.10, software-center

I just recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10, and now I can't install any software from Ubuntu software center or Terminal.  When I update, it is updating perfectly, but when I try to install any software from the Ubuntu software center, It says "Check you Internet Connection".
The screenshots are attached.

[image: Try To Install]
[image: Showing Error]

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide further details in the error window click on the arrow on **Details** please.

Try the commands below in sudo to see if refreshing your apt-get cache and removing any packages that are no longer needed.

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Once your done try update and upgrading via sudo in terminal.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

If errors come up in terminal please post in here please.

Thanks